# php give class to 3 div's then skip 3

Tags: php

I have a table with a row of 3 div's then another row or 3 div's then another and then another.

But what I'm trying to achieve is to highlight every other row. And each row contains 3 div's.

So the first row will be `.mydiv .even` and then the `.even`'s will be grey. Then the next row will be `.mydiv .odd` and then the `.odd`'s will be white.

I am using this code from css-tricks.com `($xyz++%2)` to make every other div a different class.

All help is apreciated.

---

This is my code

```
$get_new_games = mysql_query("SELECT game_title,game_description,id from games ORDER BY added_date LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_new_games)) {
$new_game_title = $row['game_title'];
$new_game_description = $row['game_description'];
$new_game_id = $row['id'];
$new_games_display .= '<div class = "game_module class-'.($xyz++%2).'"><img src = "game_thumbnails/'.$new_game_id.'/_thumb_100x100.png" class = "game_img"></div>';
}
```

Comment: Can you post some example code, for instance the for loop you're using to generate the table rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense to add the class to the row, to output the table rows in PHP, use something like this:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $rows[$i]; $i ++): ?>
<tr class="<?php echo $i % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>">
  <td>
    <div />
  </td>
  <td>
    <div />
  </td>
  <td>
    <div />
  </td>
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

The modulo operator `%` will return the remainder of the division, in this case the division is by two and any equal number will give a remainder of zero, and any unequal number will give a remainder of one.

The selector for the `div` would then be:

```
tr.odd td > div
tr.even td > div
```

this will make sure that only the top `div` in each row is selected.

**UPDATE:**

From the code you've supplied it doesn't really appear you're using a table at all (maybe you meant it in a looser sense than the actual HTML element?). Going by your code you already use the modulo in the way described above, but you need to change the following.

```
$xyz = 0;
$get_new_games = mysql_query("SELECT game_title,game_description,id from games ORDER BY added_date LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_new_games)) {
  $new_game_title = $row['game_title'];
  $new_game_description = $row['game_description'];
  $new_game_id = $row['id'];
  $new_games_display .= '<div class = "game_module class-'.($xyz++%2 ? 'odd' : 'even').'"><img src = "game_thumbnails/'.$new_game_id.'/_thumb_100x100.png" class = "game_img"></div>';
}
```

I've added the first line to initialize the variable to zero and changed the `$new_games_display`-line to `($xyz++%2 ? 'odd' : 'even')`. This will ensure that every other `div` has the class `class-odd` and the rest `class-even`.

The only issue I'm having is that the code you supplied doesn't really correspond to your initial problem, with rows of three `div`s, maybe I'm missing something -- feel free to supply more code and I'll be able to help you more.

Comment: you might want to add a note about the css selector being `.odd div` instead of `.odd`.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: good point, I've edited and added information about the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

While looping through and printing out the rows, you will use the index to determine even or odd.

```
if(!$index%2){
   echo "even";
}
else{
   echo "odd";
}
```

The % is the modulus operator, which returns the remainder when its operands are divided.

Edit:
So in your case, your last line would be

`$new_games_display .= '<div class = "game_module class-'.(($xyz++%2) ? 'odd' : 'even').'"><img src = "game_thumbnails/'.$new_game_id.'/_thumb_100x100.png" class = "game_img"></div>'`;

Comment: I'm not sure if that's gonna give 3 a class (in a row) and then 3 not a class (in a row) like even even even odd odd odd

Comment: Well, using this information, I am sure you can figure out how to do that.  Your code does not output 3divs per row, nor have you clearly expressed your question.

Comment: Excuse me? Well sorry for not clearly expressing my question, you're not perfect aswell.

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_new_games)) 
{
...
$i++;
$class = ($i%2)? "even" : "odd"; 
$new_games_display .= '<div class = "game_module class-' . $class .'"><img src = "game_thumbnails/'.$new_game_id.'/_thumb_100x100.png" class = "game_img"></div>';
}
```

instead of check `$i%2 ==0` or not you can use something like

```
 $class = ($i & 1) ? "odd" : "even";
```

or

```
if($i & 1){
    $class = "odd";
}else{
    $class = "even";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only highlighting every other row instead of groups of three rows.  You could use an `:nth-child` css selector, but using php will ensure browser compatibility since the class is hard coded.  Anyway..

```
$evenodd = false; // false indicates odd
$count = 0;

while (...) {
   ... //display
   $count++;
   if ($count == 2) {
      $evenodd = !$evenodd;
      $count = 0;
   }
}
```